# WCF set keepAliveEnable="false" not working

Tags: c#, wcf, keep-alive

In my service I need to set keepAliveEnable=false in order to work with my load balancer. Therefore I followed instruction in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128(v=vs.110).aspx) article. I did same thing mentioned in article but I am getting this error.

```
<customBinding>
   <binding name="HttpBinding" keepAliveEnabled="False"/>
</customBinding>

The Scheme cannot be computed for this binding because this CustomBinding lacks a TransportBindingElement.  Every binding must have at least one binding element that derives from TransportBindingElement.
```

Then I found set keepAliveFalse like below

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="HttpBinding" >
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport  allowCookies="false"  keepAliveEnabled="false"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

In this method service is getting started normal and I can get the responses. But in request headers still shows connection as keep alive. (I checked using firebug)
[image]

1. What is the correct way of doing this?
2. What is the end I need to set keep alive false (client or service) ?
3. Am I checking keepAlive in wrong way?

Comment: Are you using the custom binding while making service calls?

Comment: I just add service reference to client. It created binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService1" and <binding name="CustomBinding_IService1">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>